# Add a connection to KDE's Network Connections

Tags: networking, kde5

In KDE's "Connections" pane, I temporarily deleted the entry for an ethernet connection, but there is no GUI option for adding a connection. Seems odd that KDE wouldn't have an "add" button/contextual menu. What's the easiest way to add it back?

Tried resetting and reconnecting the ethernet port manually to trigger the automatic setup, but didn't have an effect.

On latest vanilla Manjaro KDE, fwiw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is an "add" button (<kbd>+</kbd>)

Just need to scroll within the box to find it. Only found it by accident.

[image]
[image]